# Eclipse plugin to colorize/visually flag entries in the Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, colors, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a way to colorize entries in Eclipse' Package Explorer:

In bigger projects you have dozens of files in a package all listed underneath each other. This makes it hard to find the file you look for (e.g. for right-click operations). So it would be nice if I could manually colorize some entries.

Does a plugin for this exist?

Comment: I am interested in this. At one point, I found a plugin that let you apply a color filter based on the project name. Not ideal, but better than nothing. Wish I could find that now though.

Comment: I suggest you use the hierarchy view instead of flat.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would ever use flat. But once you are up to having 100+ projects in a workspace, visually separating them would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one that I was using before. It lets you set rules and tints icons accordingly:

[Label Decorator](http://www.jave.de/eclipse/labeldecorator/index.html)

Comment: Latest version from 2007 which was tested on E3.3. What version of eclipse have you used it on?

Comment: Tried it out afterwards, but could not get it to work in Juno SR1. Was probably E3 that I used it in a year or two ago.

Comment: Just tried it with Indigo: Works a treat. - Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have Eclipse filter the classes you see is to use [Eclipse Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn). You create tasks that you work on and Mylyn will remember the packages and classes associated with a certain task. It will then filter out all other classes/packages. This gives you an editor that only shows the information relevant to a specific task.

I suggested Mylyn for a different problem [aswell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335713/207764) and in that answer I gave a bit more information.